# How do I copy the value not the address of a pointer in C here?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, c-strings, null-pointer

I want the value of `names[j]` put into `name` in the `diddle()` function. I tried a couple things, and either the value in `name` reflects the change to `name[j]` to `"0"` when I return it, or I get a segfault. What am I missing?

`randomGenerator` returns an integer corresponding to the index of `names[]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

char* names[9];

//char* diddle(char *names[]) {
void diddle(char *names[], char *name) {
    int i;

    while (1) {

        int j = randomGenerator(0,9);
        printf("j is %d\n",j);
        int x;
        x = strcmp(names[j],"0");
        printf("names[j] is %s and x is %d\n",names[j],x);
        if (x != 0) {
            strcpy(name,names[j]);
            strcpy(names[j],"0");
            break;
        }

    }
    //return name;
}


int main() {

    names[0] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(names[0],"foo");

    names[1] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(names[1],"bar");

    names[2] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(names[2],"baz");

    names[3] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(names[3],"qux");

    names[4] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(names[4],"zed");

    names[5] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(names[5],"pug");

    names[6] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(names[6],"unk");

    names[7] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(names[7],"fed");

    names[8] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(names[8],"hip");

    names[9] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(names[9],"gib");

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        //char *name = diddle(&names[0]);
        char *name = NULL;
        diddle(&names[0],&name);

        printf("main loop: name is %s\n", name);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        free(names[i]);
    }       
}
```

Comment: first: `names[9]` does not exist

Comment: Which warnings does your compiler show you when you compile this code? `diddle` expects a `char *name` but you provide a `char **`.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `name`.

Comment: BTW: you can have 10 times less calls to `malloc` in this piece of code. Exercise: fiind out how. Hint: there is a pattern in your code

Comment: @Jabberwocky how about... ``` names[0] =  (char *) malloc(4 * 10 * sizeof(char));
 strcpy(names[0],"foo");
 strcpy(names[1],"bar");
 strcpy(names[2],"baz");
 strcpy(names[3],"qux");
 strcpy(names[4],"zed");
 strcpy(names[5],"pug");
 strcpy(names[6],"unk");
 strcpy(names[7],"fed");
 strcpy(names[8],"hip");
 strcpy(names[9],"gib"); ```

Comment: That would not be correct. What Jabberwocky wanted to tell you is think about a loop to allocate all the memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array declared like

```
char* names[9];
```

then the valid range of indices for this array is `[0, 9)` .

So these statements

```
names[9] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
strcpy(names[9],"gib");
```

access the non-existent element of the array with invalid index `9`.

This loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    free(names[i]);
}
```

is also incorrect by the same reason.

Do not us magic numbers like 9 0r 10. Use named constants as for example

```
enum { N = 9 };
char* names[N];

//...

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    free(names[i]);
}
```

And there is no sense to declare the array `names` as a global variable. You could declare it in main.

Though the allocated memory

```
names[0] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
```

can accommodate a string of four characters

```
strcpy(names[0],"foo");
```

nevertheless such an allocation only confuses readers of the code. Instead write in this an other similar statements

```
names[0] =  (char *) malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
                                       ^^^^^
```

or just

```
names[0] =  (char *) malloc( 4 );
```

Th function `diddle`  the second parameter has the type `char *`

```
void diddle(char *names[], char *name) {
```

but in the function call

```
diddle(&names[0],&name);
```

there is used expression `&name` of the type `char **`.

As a result this statement

```
strcpy(name,names[j]);
```

invokes undefined behavior. Even if an passed expression had correct type

```
diddle(&names[0],&name);
```

nevertheless the function again had undefined behavior because the passed pointer is a null pointer. So you may not use `strcpy` with a null pointer.

Instead of the null pointer

```
char *name = NULL;
```

you could use a character array like

```
char name[4];
```